# How to add an image by pressing a button in JavaFX

Tags: image, javafx, imageview

I want to be able to press a button and an image appear on the page.
Additionally, I want to be able to place the button with Y and X coordinates, not through layouts.
Would I need to use an image view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very precise, so I hope I answer what you need.

To show an Image generally you need an `ImageView`, that is correct. For less common image formats you might need an external library.

To only show the image when the button is clicked, you have to first set the `ImageView` to not managed and not visible. Then when the button is clicked make it visible and managed and it will show.

About the absolute positioning of your button, you can override the layout children of any Parent object and set exact positions. Take a look at [this question](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwier4GDvqTWAhXNJ1AKHRsSDm4QFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F21118394%2Fexplicitly-positioning-nodes-in-javafx&usg=AFQjCNEZGi9r6jLvOyQ82ikmJwya8dKYrw).